# Installing a CA only for specific domains

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority

For many reasons, it's often convenient for organizations to have their own CA (self-signed or otherwise).

As I understand it, adding the CA certificate to a OS or browser will make it trust the organization's servers - but also open the door for the organization (or any attacker to access to the CA key) to impersonate *any server on the internet*. This is a problem, especially if the organization has a BYOD policy.

Is there any way to add a CA to popular OSs and browsers (Windows, Mac, Linux, Android, Chrome, Firefox,...) such that it is only trusted to certify *some* domains?
If there isn't, is this because of a technical limitation in the PKI system, or simply because "nobody needed it implemented yet"?

Answer (score 6):

Having a CA specific to a domain is possible with X.509, using [Name Constraints](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.10). It is not well supported, though -- many implementations will ignore the constraints. If it did work well, commercial CA could sell domain-specific subCA certificates to domain owners (that would be a technically much better solution than wildcard certificates).

In many cases where there is an "organizational CA", the users are organization *employees*, for whom the CA is an emanation from the upper spheres of the organization, i.e. (theoretically and formally) the Voice of God. In these cases, limitation to a single domain would not provide a significant security improvement, which explains the lack of sustained demand for such a feature (and, thus, lack of support from existing browsers).

Comment: And moreover, the CA is deployed by people with domain admin access, they could deploy whatever they like - spyware, another CA with no name constraints, etc.

Comment: It's good to know that at at least the format supports it. I don't understand your point about there being no significant security improvement - are you thinking about having the CA installed on company systems? I was thinking something along the lines of BYOD (I've clarified that in the question)

Comment: @paj28 Indeed, if the physical system is the organization's property. But it's very relevant with BYOD

Comment: @goncalopp - Good point. Seems you are in luck - support is more widespread than Thomas thought. http://unmitigatedrisk.com/?p=24

Comment: Do you know if these Named Constraints are user configurable or come "baked" in the certificate? I ask because most websites controlled by the Brazilian government and its branches uses a CA not trusted by any browser, and controlled by the government itself (ICP-Brasil). It would be awesome if we could trust their root certificate only for domains `.gov.br` but not for anything besides that. Instead of trusting it globally (bad) or - as many of these sites actually *instruct their users to do* - simply ignoring the warning messages that the browser shows.

Comment: "In these cases, limitation to a single domain would not provide a significant security improvement."

There would be substantial benefit, actually. For one, as a user, I don't want to trust my corp to MITM my bank connection. For the orgs themselves, they may want to limit exposure by declaring they will only issue certs only for domains which they already control. In the event of a key exposure, then, they've not assumed any liability for external sites, e.g. users' banking info.